# How to pass instance in freetds - Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to mssql server (2008 R2) from my ubuntu. I have installed freetds driver.

Below is my configuration in freetds.conf:

```
[titan]
    host = SQL_IP_ADDRESS
    tds version = 7.0
    instance = CENTERFORALLIED\MSSQLSERVER_2K8
```

Where `CENTERFORALLIED\MSSQLSERVER_2K8` is the instance name.

When I try to connect using below command:

```
tsql -S titan\MSSQLSERVER_2K8 -U user -P pass
```

OR

```
tsql -S titan -U user -P pass
```

OR

```
tsql -S SQL_IP_ADDRESS -U user -P pass
```

its not working. I am getting below error:

```
locale is "en_IN"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from CENTERFORALLIED\SQLEXPRESS Line 1:
        "Login failed for user 'ibuser'."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
       Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I am not sure why this is trying to connect to `SQLEXPRESS` instance. My instance is `MSSQLSERVER_2K8` and I am explicitly mentioned it in config file and even tried in arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`instance`](http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm) is `MSSQLSERVER_2K8` (w/o the hostname part). You can alternatively conf directly the [`port`](http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm).

Note that resolving the instance to a port relies on the [SQL Server Browser Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) being enabled and started. If is not started then you *must* use the port explicitly, and the port *must* be statically configured (not dynamic).

Comment: Any idea how do I know the port? I have access to RDP.

Comment: 1) Read [Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx) you'll also understand how to see what is configured. 2) Look into your SQL Server ERRORLOG file, it will have a line near top (~100 lines) saying something like 'instance is configured to listen on blah:blah'. Make sure the port is *not* dynamic, if it is you will have to use instance name instead.